# Is passwordless OTP based authentication SOC2 compliant?

Tags: authentication, passwords, one-time-password

I have a client requirement to implement login without password. During sign in an otp will be sent to the user's email address and the user can use it to login. This will have an expiry.

No password will be used here. Is the implementation SOC2 compliant and according to US IT laws?

Comment: What US IT Law are you talking about?

Comment: SOC2 is not a technical standard. The assessor makes all the calls based on best practices. Since "passwordless" is not "best practice" it is unlikely to get approved by the assessor.

Comment: @schroeder – [passwordless authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passwordless_authentication) (in certain contexts) is coming to a best common practice near you  – see [Gartner](https://www.gartner.com/smarterwithgartner/embrace-a-passwordless-approach-to-improve-security), [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2021/09/15/the-passwordless-future-is-here-for-your-microsoft-account/), [(Cisco) Duo](https://duo.com/solutions/passwordless), [Okta](https://www.okta.com/passwordless-authentication/), …

Comment: @AdamKatz yes, I'm well aware. But what zero trust methods are emerging are not what the OP outlined. Those vendors are talking about continuous, dynamic reauthentication.

Comment: @schroeder – Agreed. That'll be the first of those "certain contexts" I was referring to. I expect we'll eventually get beyond that for low-value accounts (like those that have no messaging or financial hooks).

Comment: @AdamKatz I just wanted to make sure that the OP was clear because the same terms were being used for different concepts and your wiki article would lead someone to believe that the design in the question might be viable (and by extension, might pass a SOC 2 audit). It's not a different context, but a completely different concept.